# Copy SVG/HTML content from external file using JS without Ajax?

Tags: javascript, ajax, html, svg

I would like to use JS to open an SVG file, copy the svg, then paste the svg into the the DOM I'm working with. Is this possible without using Ajax?

I have tried using the svg as an object, but ultimately I want to be able to wrap the svg in an a tag, which I am unable to do with an object:

```
document.getElementById(myElement).innerHTML='<object data="/svg_location.svg" type="image/svg+xml"></object>')
```

html

```
 <a href='#'>
       <div id="myElement">
         [object--not linkable]
       </div>
    </a>
```

Comment: First off, you use `innerHTML` wrong, second, if that file is located on the server you will need Ajax to get it.

Comment: Open the target page in your browser, press ctrl+u, then ctrl+a followed by ctrl+c

Comment: post valentines day snark and rudeness or what? First, @LGSon, can you explain or elaborate on *why* `innerHTML` is "wrong". (if you mean the parenthesis, I just updated it, but still same issue). The file is in the same directory as the html and `innerHTML` works, I just can't add the a tags. @KevinB the svg code is too long to do that.

Comment: Yes, I meant parenthesis. Was saying you used it wrong rude?

Answer (score 0):

Yes it's possible without AJAX. I answered a similar question from someone else yesterday. I'm not sure how to mark yours as a duplicate so I'll just link to that answer: [Trigger click on SVG image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54706991/trigger-click-on-svg-image/54707413#54707413)

Comment: Yes I suppose it is, strictly speaking :) Can you not just do this: `<a href="foo.htm"><img src="/svg_location.svg"></a>`?

Answer (score 0):

How about an `iframe`?

```html
<iframe id="svgLoader" src="https://www.your.svg.com"></iframe>
```

And later:

```
var svgCode = $('#svgLoader').innerHTML;
```